# Vue router can't loading component

Tags: vue.js, components, vue-router

main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App';
import router from './routes/Route';
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App),
  router
})
```

Route.js:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import Routes from "./Routes";
Vue.use(VueRouter);
export default new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  Routes
});
```

Routes.js:

```
import About from '../components/About';
import Work from '../components/Work';
import Contact from '../components/Contact';
export default [
    {
      path: '/about',
      name: 'about',
      component: About
    }
]
```

Menu.vue:

```
<template>
    <div class="menu-top">
        <router-link class="menu-href-route" to="/about"><span>About</span></router-link>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: 'Menu',
}
</script>
```

Hello.vue:

```
<template>
    <div class="hello">
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import About from './About';
    export default {
        name: "Hello"
    }
</script>
```

About.vue:

```
<template>
    <div>
        About test text
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "about"
    }
</script>
```

I create in file Route.js routing and export him to main.js. Next in file Routes.js I create path to componentns. In file Menu.js is router-link. And file Hello.vue have router-view. About.vue is view component. I don't know why component About.vue is not loading in file Hello.vue, when I have address: `http://localhost:8080/about`. I reinstall node and vue-router, but this not helping.

Comment: I think you should register the about component to the hello component via the "components: {"about":about}"- attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As js is case-sensitive so try to make change like this

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import Routes from "./Routes";
Vue.use(VueRouter);
export default new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: Routes
});
```

Comment: Yes, I should use attribute  `routes: Routes`. Thanks for help ;)